# Input type number returns null for event input on operator(+, -)

Tags: javascript, html, input, addeventlistener, dom-events

When `<input>` tag of type `number`. which is subscribed for `input` event

It returns `""` empty string for input value `+` even though there are numbers value in the input field.

```html
<input type="number" value="123" id="abc"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#abc").on('input', function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    });
  </script>
```

I just need to know why this behavior happens, it would be really helpful if there is any resource online explaining it. 
The expectation was `'123+'` but it was returning `''`

I know by logically it makes sense to return `''` but i need an explanation regarding this behaviour

Comment: why do you use type number ?

Comment: If a number input contains non-numeric values then its `value` is always `""`

Comment: So, you are expecting your input field to evaluates an expression like `"2+3"` and gives  you a `5`? I don't believe that is possible if you want that.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha I need just number to be input type, but  characters '+' '-' 'e' are also allowed by input type number.

Comment: @vikasgupta Is there any document regarding this or any article explaining this behaviour

Comment: @Shidersz I don't expect to be evaluated i just need the value available in the input element. the expectation was it would return `123+` but its returning ''. I just need to know why this behaviour happens .

Comment: [@Amernath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475089/amerrnath) there were a discussion regarding it in [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2203)

Answer (score 0):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Validation) input type number automatically invalidate an entry that isn't a number.

```js
$("#abc").on('input', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="123" id="abc" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use input type text and validate the input type to accept numbers and special chars(+,-,etc).

There is already a bug reported for the same, many browser vendors has a disagreement on placing chars to input type number.

[bugzila link for the same problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528)

Answer (score 0):

As the type suggests, for Input type "number", all other input except numbers are considered as invalid input. So Whatever you type, you would get empty string in case of non-numeric value.
If You want to identify about these invalid input, then you can use this workaround.

```
$("#abc").on('input', function (event) {
        // Any Non-numeric value 
        if (this.validity.badInput) {
             console.log('Bad',event.target.value);
        }else{
                console.log('OK',event.target.value);
        }
    });
```